# How do I add a PKPass to the Apple Wallet from within my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, wallet, passkit

I'd like the user to be able to add their own `PKPass` with their name to Apple Wallet by tapping a button in the app.
I have created the CustomPass.pkpass with the "primaryFields" "label" set to the user's name. Would I update the "label" inside the `pass.json` before it's added to the Wallet somehow?
I have found very little info about how to do this. Possibly with `PKAddPassesViewController`?

Is it possible to add the pass to the wallet this way without using a webServiceURL / PassKit API?

Comment: You cannot update a pass by simply changing a value in pass.json.  You need to sign and zip a new .pkpass bundle.  You can’t do this within an app because that would compromise your private key.  So you need a server to compile and sign the pass and make it available to your app.  But you don’t need to implement the webservice to do this.

Comment: @PassKit thank you! How would I do this without the web service? Is there documentation about how to use a server to compile and sign the pass without implementing a webservice as we've described?

Comment: There are dozens of libraries for compiling passes (search GitHub for pkpass).  Choose one that fits your preferred language and can meet your needs. You'll then need code in your iOS app to fetch the pass from your server and present it to the PKAddPassViewController for the user to add to their Wallet (you cannot add passes automatically without the user's consent).

Answer (score 0):

After updating pass.json, you need to re-create and sign the pass bundle, as commented above. This is best done using a web service: for in-app signing one would need to distribute the signing keys with the app, which is a security risk.

Apple provides an example for local signing though, the *signpass* source code in https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip .